# How to retrieve 7th row in a table using SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with some number of records in it say the table is Student and it has a column named total_mark  . Now I need to fetch the details of the student who is 7th largest total  from the total_mark column . How to perform this operation in SQL SERVER 2008?

Comment: 7th by what standard? SQL doesn't guarantee an order unless you specify it in your query

Comment: Table rows do not have an intrinsic order. You need to do something like `select top 7 * from students order by [somecolumn]`, then take the last row returned.

Answer (score 2):

First, define what you mean by "7th". 7th in age? 7th in IQ? 7th in height? Whatever.

```
WITH
RankedStudents AS ( 
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY <Whatever> ) AS RowNumber FROM <Schema>.<Object>
)
SELECT * 
FROM RankedStudents 
WHERE RowNumber = 7 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

First select the top 7, then reverse the ordering and take just the first row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 7 *
    FROM RankedStudents 
    ORDER BY total_mark desc) x
ORDER BY total_mark
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT total_mark,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_mark DESC)AS RANKED FROM SN_DB)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE   WHERE RANKED = 7
```